# Добавить растровое изображения в svg

Tags: svg, изображения

Есть ли какой-то способ вставить растровое изображение в svg файл?
 Нашел тег `<image>`, но при такой записи какой-то объект добавляется в svg (в inkscape выделяется), но просто белый фон:

```
<image src="D:\project\хлам\image.png" height="79.375" width="79.375" />
```

Добавил картинку прямо в редактор (вставил) получаю очень страшную картину в результате, если открыть svg через блокнот (огромная куча символов):

```
xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAASwAAAEsCAYAAAB5fY51AAA3mklEQVR42uzcXYhMcRjHcReKG5Qr
JYplLUvZsKy3jYS4QIlahbznbUXLXkit9ZbVuuAGRcSV4kK2vRHtzVJkhfUyM2TJnNnZ2dmXmfG2
5vH8z56NKKzNzJ4z30/92qlpr57/+c05/zln+gAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA...
```

и еще 230 строчек этом духе.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Автор вопроса, предполагая использование тега `<image>` для добавления растрового изображения в `svg` был на верном пути, но нужно довести всё до конца.*

### Одна картинка заполняет всё пространство svg

Для этого выбираем параметры `viewBox` равными размерам растровой картинки и устанавливаем `width` и `height` растрового изображения равными 100%

Стиль - `style="border:1px solid red;"` в шапке svg файла служит для указания границы области действия svg

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       width="1080" height="900" viewBox="0 0 1080 900" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" style="border:1px solid red;" >  
<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1DGN.png" width="100%" height="100%" />
</svg>
```

### Одна картинка заполняет 50%  пространства svg

Команда  `preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"` помещает картинку в левый верхний угол svg

Размеры для растровой картинки: `width="50%" height="50%"`

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       width="1080" height="900" viewBox="0 0 1080 900" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" style="border:1px solid red;" >  
<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1DGN.png" width="50%" height="50%" />
</svg>
```

Теперь появилась возможность позиционирования картинки внутри пространства svg.

### Позиционирование растровой картинки внутри файла svg

Для этого используется команда -  `transform="translate(X Y)"`

Возьмем к примеру 4 одинаковых растровых картинки и разместим их по углам svg полотна.

Для смещения изображения в правый верхний угол - `transform="translate(540 0)"`
Для смещения изображения в правый нижний угол - `transform="translate(540 450)"`

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       width="1080" height="900" viewBox="0 0 1080 900" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" style="border:1px solid red;" >  
<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1DGN.png" width="50%" height="50%" />
<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1DGN.png" transform="translate(540 0)" width="50%" height="50%" /> 
<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1DGN.png" transform="translate(0 450)" width="50%" height="50%" /> 
<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1DGN.png" transform="translate(540 450)" width="50%" height="50%" />
</svg>
```

### Отдельное масштабирование для каждой картинки

- Изменением ширины и высоты картинки (`width="25%"` `height="25%"`) в теге
  `<image>` получаем разные масштабы картинки.
- Применением команды `transform="translate(600 0)"` позиционируем
  картинку

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       width="1080" height="900" viewBox="0 0 1080 900" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" style="border:1px solid red;" >  
<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1DGN.png" width="50%" height="50%" />
<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1DGN.png" transform="translate(600 0)" width="25%" height="25%" /> 
<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1DGN.png" transform="translate(900 0)" width="12.5%" height="12.5%" />

</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

К таким картинкам можно обратится на прямую через  `src="путь.."`.
Предварительно добавьте её в папку к картинкам, или в то место где вы храните все свою картинки. В качестве примера прикрепляю код, где вставляется картинка залитая на хостинг (кстати очень удобно).

**PS**
Если вы хотит открывать картинку svg прямо в своей среде разработке, то вам может пригодятся спецальные плагины, которые помогаю это сделать.
Я использую `Visual studio code` и плагин `SVG Viewer`- [ссылка](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=cssho.vscode-svgviewer).

```css
.papa {
  width: 250px;
}

.mama {
  width: 100px;
}

.baby {
  width: 50px;
}

img {
  vertical-align: top;
}

body {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<img class="papa" src="https://s.cdpn.io/3/kiwi.svg">

<img class="mama" src="https://s.cdpn.io/3/kiwi.svg">

<img class="baby" src="https://s.cdpn.io/3/kiwi.svg">
```

Источник: [ссылка](http://area53.ru/html5/kak-vstavit-svg-v-html.html)

Comment: спасибо за ответ, но не совсем то, мне не нужно вставлять svg в html (с этим проблем нет). Необходимо запихнуть в svg файл изображение, например, png. В определенное место, с определенным размером.